# How to ask about outside temperature?

Tags: sentence-construction

Which sentence is correct:
 1. Do you know what temperature it is outside?
 2. Do you know what the temperature is outside?
 3. Do you know what the outside temperature is?
 4. Do you know what outside temperature is?
I think all of them are correct except for sentence 4. 
What do you natives think? Help, please

Comment: First you need to tell us which one you think is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1, 2, and 3 are all valid ways to ask this question. The last one is the only one that would make anyone think you don't speak English well.

To me, 2 feels like the most formal way to ask, while 1 and 3 feel more casual.